# What does "the wrong volume is in the drive" mean?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, chkdsk

My phone took a bath in the river a few days ago. The phone is dead, but the SD card works still. However it is excruciatingly slow! The average read speed is well under 50kb/s. To copy 32GB of data over would take absolutely ages!

I did a chkdsk, and it says that the wrong volume is in the drive...

[image: Problem]

All three options (`Try again`, `Continue` and `Cancel`) both just make the message prompt again. I have tried pulling the card and reinserting it but this doesn't work, and makes no difference

1. What does this message mean?
2. How can I fix it, and make `chkdsk` work?

Comment: Based on the error I would say that SD card actually is not working and more then likely is damaged, I highly suspect there won't be a good way to fix the problem that exists on the card itself.

Comment: On the chance that some water may have gotten inside the card, get a bunch of dessicant packets, like what are used in medicine bottles, and put them and the card into an air-tight container.   If you don't have a bunch of those, bury the card in some (uncooked) rice kernels in an air-tight container. Leave it for about a week in a warm location.  If you have an oven with a "keep warm" setting, use a heat-proof, air-tight container and leave it there for a few days.  Then test again (let it cool down for several hours before testing if you go the "keep warm" route).

Comment: What type of SD card?  is it a micro? or one of them with a plastic shell that could potentially still be holding moisture inside?

Comment: @Psycogeek. Its a micro

Comment: @fixer1234: WHat sort of temperature should I use? Is 50 degrees in the oven OK? That's what the manual says to keep food warm on

Comment: I'm not an SD card chef.  :-)  I'm just guessing somewhere in the range of 100-120 degrees F should be safe (that's normal operating temperature in some areas of the world).  The idea is to provide some energy to help any water evaporate but not get so hot that it affects the circuitry (or melts the plastic).  Oven thermostats are often inaccurate by 5 or 10 degrees, and they cycle on and off so temperatures could exceed the setting.  So maybe  a setting of 100 F.